# CSS Border Transition - Weird effect

Tags: css

When I hover over the corner of the element I am getting a weird constant hover and hover out effect, how can I fix this?

**HTML**

```
<h2>
HELLO
</h2>
```

**CSS**

```
h2 {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(2,35,64,0.58);
    width: calc(100% - 97px);
    height: calc(100% - 88px);
    line-height: calc(100% + 70px);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    border: solid 20px rgba(2,35,64,0);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
    cursor: pointer;
}

h2:hover {
    border: solid 5px #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 25px;
    background: transparent;
}

h2.woocommerce-loop-category__title:hover {
    border: solid 5px #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 25px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xc7vjstn/1/

Comment: you are adding margin, so you are creating a space and the mouse is unhovering the h2 and the space disappear, and so on

Comment: Instead of `weird` word , you should describe what you want to be ..:)

Answer (score 0):

change the background from transparent to what ever color you want and you will see the content plus if you want to keep it online like small box then margin and padding is what you need to play with.

```
h2:hover {
border: solid 5px #FFF;
padding: 10px;
margin: 25px;
background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `margin` in `h2:hover` is causing the behavior removing the margin fixed the problem

```
h2:hover {
    border: solid 5px #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    /*margin: 25px; */
    background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, please check the live example below:

```css
h2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(2, 35, 64, 0.58);
  width: calc(100% - 97px);
  height: calc(100% - 88px);
  line-height: calc(100% + 70px);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  border: solid 20px rgba(2, 35, 64, 0);
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}

h2:hover {
  background: transparent;
  -ms-transform: scale(0.9);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

```html
<h2>
  HELLO
</h2>
```